# How to cut out the polygon if stands at two tiffs?

Tags: python, rasterio

I would like to cut out the polygon from tiff. The problem is that the polygon stands on two tiffs. I was thinking about the solution and I can create a raster mosaic from 2 tiffs. Is it good idea or not? In my code I have to set up the tiff where my polygon stands and my idea will work. But I am not an expert and maybe someone knows better solution. I have crs of polygon and tiffs.

```
from shapely import geometry
import rasterio
import shapely.wkt
from rasterio.mask import mask
import time

#coordinates
coo = shapely.wkt.loads("POLYGON ((644299.5500000000465661 493820.6500000000232831, 644297.6899999999441206 493821.1599999999743886, 644295.3699999999953434 493819.4299999999930151, 644295.7600000000093132 493818.9099999999743886, 644290.2700000000186265 493814.8300000000162981, 644289.8800000000046566 493815.3200000000069849, 644288.9100000000325963 493814.5999999999767169, 644281.0699999999487773 493824.9600000000209548, 644278.6800000000512227 493823.1799999999930151, 644279.7399999999906868 493821.7100000000209548, 644275.4100000000325963 493818.5800000000162981, 644274.3900000000139698 493819.9899999999906868, 644263.6199999999953434 493811.7800000000279397, 644264.6300000000046566 493810.4099999999743886, 644261.9499999999534339 493808.4199999999837019, 644260.9399999999441206 493809.7899999999790452, 644257.5200000000186265 493807.1900000000023283, 644258.0300000000279397 493806.4799999999813735, 644257.7900000000372529 493806.0999999999767169, 644257.2199999999720603 493805.2700000000186265, 644256.6199999999953434 493804.4799999999813735, 644255.9599999999627471 493803.7199999999720603, 644255.2600000000093132 493802.9899999999906868, 644254.1500000000232831 493801.9799999999813735, 644253.3599999999860302 493801.3599999999860302, 644251.6500000000232831 493800.1199999999953434, 644249.9499999999534339 493799.0599999999976717, 644248.9899999999906868 493798.5399999999790452, 644246.0999999999767169 493797.4299999999930151, 644245.4699999999720603 493798.2899999999790452, 644242.0200000000186265 493795.6799999999930151, 644243.2700000000186265 493794.0200000000186265, 644240.4799999999813735 493791.9299999999930151, 644239.2399999999906868 493793.5800000000162981, 644228.5000000000000000 493785.5599999999976717, 644229.5300000000279397 493784.1900000000023283, 644225.1899999999441206 493780.9199999999837019, 644224.1600000000325963 493782.2899999999790452, 644223.0000000000000000 493781.3400000000256114, 644222.6700000000419095 493778.8499999999767169, 644225.5100000000093132 493775.0200000000186265, 644226.7700000000186265 493775.9699999999720603, 644229.0400000000372529 493772.9699999999720603, 644227.8000000000465661 493772.1599999999743886, 644231.8399999999674037 493766.9699999999720603, 644228.8800000000046566 493764.6300000000046566, 644229.5200000000186265 493763.7800000000279397, 644225.7500000000000000 493760.8499999999767169, 644225.4000000000232831 493761.2700000000186265, 644225.6300000000046566 493761.4799999999813735, 644225.3000000000465661 493761.9099999999743886, 644222.3199999999487773 493759.6599999999743886, 644209.0899999999674037 493777.1199999999953434, 644208.7299999999813735 493777.9199999999837019, 644208.4399999999441206 493778.7600000000093132, 644208.1500000000232831 493779.9500000000116415, 644207.9499999999534339 493781.1099999999860302, 644207.8599999999860302 493782.0000000000000000, 644208.1300000000046566 493783.7800000000279397, 644208.3199999999487773 493784.2899999999790452, 644208.5000000000000000 493784.6900000000023283, 644208.7900000000372529 493785.1799999999930151, 644209.7199999999720603 493786.2600000000093132, 644210.1700000000419095 493786.6300000000046566, 644211.0899999999674037 493787.1699999999837019, 644227.5699999999487773 493799.7199999999720603, 644226.1500000000232831 493800.9000000000232831, 644237.3499999999767169 493809.2500000000000000, 644239.3699999999953434 493806.5300000000279397, 644240.8699999999953434 493807.1099999999860302, 644242.2900000000372529 493807.7999999999883585, 644243.1400000000139698 493809.1500000000232831, 644243.7900000000372529 493809.9199999999837019, 644244.5899999999674037 493810.6599999999743886, 644245.3900000000139698 493811.2600000000093132, 644246.0000000000000000 493811.6300000000046566, 644246.7299999999813735 493811.9899999999906868, 644247.2900000000372529 493812.2199999999720603, 644248.0400000000372529 493812.5100000000093132, 644248.6999999999534339 493812.7199999999720603, 644249.1899999999441206 493813.1500000000232831, 644249.5000000000000000 493813.5300000000279397, 644250.0000000000000000 493814.1599999999743886, 644250.6500000000232831 493815.0700000000069849, 644248.8199999999487773 493817.8400000000256114, 644259.8199999999487773 493826.0100000000093132, 644260.5600000000558794 493824.4400000000023283, 644283.4899999999906868 493841.6199999999953434, 644299.5500000000465661 493820.6500000000232831))")
#coo = coo.buffer(2)

#cutting
with rasterio.open('C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/73852_944730_N-34-139-A-a-2-4.tif') as src:
    out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, [coo], crop=True)
    out_meta = src.meta
    out_meta.update(
        {
            "driver": "GTiff",
            "height": out_image.shape[1],
            "width": out_image.shape[2],
            "transform": out_transform,
        }
    )
    with rasterio.open('C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/test.tif', 'w', **out_meta) as dest:
        dest.write(out_image)
```

Image:

[image]